# Theming issues with roboelectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm new to Robolectric testing in general on Android. I'm getting:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

In the Gradle file,I am using the following dependencies

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile ('com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.0.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }

In the AndroidManifest file,
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 25

In the styles file,I am using the following theme



<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

I google for the error but no solution works.
So,please help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you see in test log message like "AndroidManifest.xml" not found?